# Typescript + Angular expose service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, encapsulation

I'm using typescript and angular on a project. When i want to expose service's method i do the following :

```
export class MyService implements IService {

    //Public method
    public myMethod: Function;

    public constructor() {

        this.myMethod= this._myMethod;

    }

    private _myMethod(): void {
       //...
    }
```

When i work on service which get many method, i don't have to scroll to see method's definition so that's great. But now when i'm using my service's method in another service or controller, i can't see signature of my method... So i'm loosing typescript advantages...

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are the methods listed in the `IService` interface ? 
2. Are you declaring the injected service in the controller to be of type `IService` ?

Comment: No, currently i'm not using IService.

Comment: That's why you're not seeing the signature/intellisense. You need to specify on your declaration in the DI in the controller that your service is of the type you say it is.

Comment: Meaning `function (myService: IService) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you need to give your function definition a signature

```
class MyService {
    public myMethod: () => void; //don't use Function

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod = this.myMethod;
    }

    _myMethod = () => {

    }
```

}

However a better approach is to define an interface:

```
interface IMyService extends IService {
    myMethod: () => void;
}

class MyService implements IMyService {
    constructor() {

    }

    myMethod = () => {

    }
}
```